# search bar inside a list item

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a search bar inside a list item.

```
 <li id="searchArea" style="width: 400px; float: none;">
 <span>     

  <img src="/ProfiletenModified/Images/searchicon18x18.png" style="
    height: 22px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 22px;

    float: left;
  ">

  <input id="searchtextbox" type="text" autocomplete="off" style=" 
    border: 1px solid #fff;
  ">

  <span></span>
</span>
</li>
```

but the problem is that the image appears very far from the input. they both don't fit well with each other. How to do this?

Comment: INLINE element cannot have width. Instead, use inline-block or block

Comment: every floated element is displayed as block, you shouldn't display them inline

Comment: Some image about how does it look like and what exactly do you expect would be helpful.

Comment: I want like a bar in which on left side appears the the image and on the right appear the input element. but when I place them there appears a distance between them and there is no clue as to what is causing the distance between them

Comment: What's up with all the span tags?

Comment: Don't know I was trying to make it work.. it is the same with and without the spans..

Comment: What about to make them float both, they'll stick together.

Comment: actually I floated them but then the <li> goes out of the effect... I tried setting the overflow:hidden to no effect on li... that was actually the case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As GCyrillus said, you would need to have both elements (the image and the text input) float together using `float: left`.

See this little Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jdevfox/645qH/3/

All without `<spam>`--I mean `<span>` tags. ;)

Comment: actually I floated them but then the <li> goes out of the effect... I tried setting the overflow:hidden to no effect on li... that was actually the case..